# Difference between 'dont avoir besoin' and 'en avoir besoin'

Tags: grammaire

French politician says

> C'est de liberté dont notre économie a besoin.

In my textbook I have found this phrase

> Tous ceux qui en ont besoin toucheront une bourse.

Why in the second example we use `en` instead of `dont`? Merci

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Réponse principalement en français accompagnée par la traduction des essentiels en anglais entre parenthèses.

> Notre économie *a besoin de liberté*. (rappel : avoir besoin *de*)

[*Dont* est un pronom relatif](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-29253.php) qui remplace de + antécédent dans la subordonnée relative. Ici, *dont* remplace donc *de liberté*. (It is a relative pronoun which replaces *de* + antecedent in the relative subordinate.)

> C'est de liberté **dont** notre économie a besoin.

Autre exemple :

> J'ai besoin de ces stylos.
>
> Ce sont ces stylos dont j'ai besoin.

Ici, *dont* remplace *de ce stylos*.

La construction avec *c'est/ce sont* comme ci-dessus s'appelle **[mise en relief](https://leflepourlescurieux.fr/la-mise-en-relief-b1/)**, une tournure grammaticale très importante en français. (The framing device c’est . . . qui/que/dont is very frequently used in spoken and written French to
highlight a particular element. French Grammar in Context, p. 211.)

---

Concernant la seconde phrase de la question. (Regarding the second question.)

> Tous ceux qui ont besoin *d'argent/de support financier/etc.* (hypothétiquement) toucheront une bourse.

*En* est ici un [pronom personnel complément](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-105600.php) qui remplace *d'argent/de suppport/etc.*. (En is here a personal pronoun complement replacing...)

> Tous ceux qui en ont besoin toucheront une bourse.

Pour aller plus loin :

https://www.lingoda.com/en/french/learning-material/cefr/B1.2/les-doubles-pronoms-1/download

https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/chroniq/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_autr84vWAiHFbX6w&page=9OU4XXgOiRWE.html

http://www.aidenet.eu/grammaire12a.htm

Answer (score 2):

When *dont* has a possessive meaning, it can be translated by *whose*, *of which*:

> *La Ville **dont** le prince est un enfant*
>
> The City **Whose** Prince is a Child

When it has no possessive meaning, it can be translated by *that*, *whom*, *which* or just skipped in English:

> *C'est le livre **dont** je t'ai parlé*
>
> It's the book (**that**) I talk you about.

In the first sentence, there is no possessive meaning:

> *C'est de liberté **dont** notre économie a besoin.*

It is equivalent to the following sentences:

> *La liberté, c'est **ce dont** notre économie a besoin.*
>
> *La liberté, c'est **de cela dont** notre économie a besoin.*
>
> *La liberté, c'est **de quoi** notre économie a besoin.*

They can be translated to:

> Liberty, this is what our economy is in need of.

or maybe:

> Liberty, this is **that** our economy is in need of.

Literally :

> It is (of) liberty **that** our economy is in need **of**.

---

In the second sentence, ***en*** is close to the English "**it**":

> *Tous ceux qui **en** ont besoin toucheront une bourse.*

means:

> *Tous ceux qui ont besoin **d'une bourse** toucheront une bourse*

Literally :

> All of those who need **it** will get a scholarship.

While *it* and *that* can sometimes be used interchangeably, *en* and *dont* do not span the same range of meanings.

Comment: You just can't explain grammar though translation to a language that uses a different grammar.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Yes, my initial wording was definitely lacking explanations.

Comment: I don't understand your answer, *what* doesn't fit at all to translate *dont* here. (*that* is much closer in almost every case)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat  You are right. *What* was more there to translate *ce* than *dont* in my examples. Answer reworked.